# Logout from different applications signed in with the same Azure AD user

Tags: azure-active-directory, logout

I have two different applications connecting with 2 different Azure ADs but the user of a single AD is present in other AD as a guest user. Both the applications use Azure Authentication and my motive is to integrate both the applications and give the end user an experience of working in a single application.

When a user authenticates into the first application, he does not require to sign-in again for the second application.

My issue is that if the user logged out from the first application, he still remains signed-in on the second.

For example, if I logged in to the Azure portal using my credentials, and want to access the Power BI portal at the same time, I do not have to re-enter my password working on the same browser. But if I signed out from Azure portal, I remained signed-in to Power BI portal until I manually signed out.

For my applications, I want the user experience to be like in G Suite. If I log in to my Gmail account and access google drive with no need to sign-in again and if I log out from Gmail, I am logged out from google drive too and vice versa.

Please suggest if there is a way to implement the same functionality for my applications using Azure AD authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely enable Single Sign Out.

In the Accounts Controller you need to add a SingleSignOut action.

```
public ActionResult SingleSignOut(string redirectUri)
        {
            if (redirectUri == null)
                ViewBag.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44308/";
            else
                ViewBag.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            return View();
        }
```

See [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out/) and the [accompanying repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out).

[This reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-single-sign-out-protocol-reference) is also helpful.